# Sending data from datagrid to reportview using visual studio 2015

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015

I have manage to add the reportview to my visual studio 2015 project but my code is not working

here is the code:

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Imports Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms

Public Class FRMREPORTS
    Dim CN As OleDbConnection = Nothing
    Dim CM As OleDbCommand = Nothing
    Dim CN_S As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & Application.StartupPath & "\FILECAB.accdb"
    Dim SQL_S As String = ""
    Dim UP_STR As String = ""
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        GET_DATA()
        LOAD_REPORT()
        RVIEW.RefreshReport()
    End Sub

    Public Sub GET_DATA()

        Try
            Dim SQL_R As String = "SELECT * From ITEMS"

            Dim CN As New OleDbConnection(CN_S)
            Dim D_A As New OleDbDataAdapter(SQL_R, CN)
            Dim DS As New DataSet()

            CN.Open()

            D_A.Fill(DS, "ITEM_TABLE")

            CN.Close()

            DG_ITMES.DataSource = DS.Tables("ITEM_TABLE")

            'Dim RDS As ReportDataSource = New ReportDataSource("ITEM_TABLE", DS.Tables)

            'RVIEW.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(RDS)

            With DG_ITMES
                .Columns(0).HeaderCell.Value = "ID"
                .Columns(1).HeaderCell.Value = "Category"
                .Columns(2).HeaderCell.Value = "Description"
                .Columns(3).HeaderCell.Value = "Unit"

                .Columns(0).Visible = False

                .Columns(1).Width = 150
                .Columns(2).Width = 300
                .Columns(3).Width = 150

                .Columns(3).DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
                .ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
            End With

            SQL_R = Nothing
            If CN.State = ConnectionState.Open Then CN.Close()
            D_A = Nothing
            DS = Nothing
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(Err.Description)
        End Try
    End Sub
    Public Sub LOAD_REPORT()
        Try
            RVIEW.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear()


            Dim DT As New DataTable
            With DT
                .Columns.Add("ID")
                .Columns.Add("Category")
                .Columns.Add("Description")
                .Columns.Add("Unit")
            End With

            For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DG_ITMES.Rows
                DT.Rows.Add(row.Cells(0).Value, row.Cells(1).Value, row.Cells(2).Value, row.Cells(3).Value)
            Next

            Dim RDS As ReportDataSource = New ReportDataSource(DT.TableName, DT)

            RVIEW.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(RDS)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(Err.Description)
        End Try
    End Sub

End Class
```

When I run this one this what I get from the report view "The source of the report definition has not been specified"

[image]

Comment: The error message is pretty clear -> you never told the ReportViewer which report to show.   Either set the report via the designer or via code.

Comment: Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: It looks like you're creating the source at runtime and assigning it.  The thing you may need after `RVIEW.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(RDS)` is `RVIEW.DataBind()` .  As you're not actually being provided an error in that code, my theory is the binding method has to be called.

Comment: how do i do that?

Comment: @TnTinMn can you pls give me a sample on how to do that... thanks

Comment: `"can you pls give me a sample"` - The exact code depends on the source of the RDLC (embedded resource, file on disk, etc.).  I think the best option is to refer you to: [Walkthrough: Using a Database Data Source with the ReportViewer Windows Forms Control in Local Processing Mode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251724.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the support :)

Comment: I have manage to eliminate that issue now, i created a blank rdlc file and call that in the code but my problem now is that the data from my datagrid is not showing in the report....

Comment: here is the code: "dg_item" is the datagrid
                        Dim DT As New DataTable
            With DT
                .Columns.Add("ID")
                .Columns.Add("Category")
                .Columns.Add("Description")
                .Columns.Add("Unit")
            End With

            For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DG_ITMES.Rows
                DT.Rows.Add(row.Cells(0).Value, row.Cells(1).Value, row.Cells(2).Value, row.Cells(3).Value)
            Next

Comment: RVIEW.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = "Report1.rdlc"
            RVIEW.LocalReport.ReportPath = "C:\Users\Laurence\Desktop\REPORT\TEST_REPORT\TEST_REPORT\Report1.rdlc"
            Dim RDS As ReportDataSource = New ReportDataSource("ITEM_TABLE", DT)
            RVIEW.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(RDS)
            RVIEW.LocalReport.Refresh()
            RVIEW.RefreshReport()